# What is « en » in « J'en ai marre de » ?

Tags: grammaire, expressions-idiomatiques, formulation-idiomatique, en, de

Je sais que en général le pronom « en » peut remplacer la construction « de + nom. », donc, je suis un peu confus parce que dans la phrase « j'en ai marre de » on a déjà un « en », et je ne sais pas pourquoi on a besoin de un « de » aussi. Par exemple:

> J'**en** ai marre **de** ce virus !

J'aurais pensé que je pourrais dire

> J'ai marre **de** ce virus !

ou, si « le virus » est connu,

> J'**en** ai marre !

parce que comme d'habitude, « en » remplace « de [ce virus] ». Mais apparemment, il faut utiliser les deux.

Merci.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Votre remarque est très pertinente car sur le plan théorique vous avez tout à fait raison: le mot "*en*" de votre phrase est superfétatoire, en effet.

Cependant, l'expression "*j'en ai marre*" s'est figée à force d'usage, ainsi "*en*" s'y est collé indépendamment du reste de la phrase, et ne peut donc plus en être ôté.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse, c'est logique.

Answer (score 3):

À la base la présence de *en* dans *en avoir marre* s'explique parce que cette locution (apparue au XIX<sup>e</sup>s.) est une des nombreuses expressions<sup>1</sup> calquées sur ***en avoir assez***, moins familière et plus ancienne (XII-XIII<sup>e</sup> s.).

Donc pour en savoir plus sur ce *en* on peut se pencher sur les ouvrages de grammaire en cherchant à *en avoir assez*. Tout en sachant que ceci n'est ni spécifique à *en avoir assez* (et ses calques), ni même à *en*.

*En* (et *y*) sont des pronoms dits « faibles» dont la valeur sémantique est très imprécise. Consultons deux ouvrages de grammaire.

***Le bon usage*** (§ 503, 10<sup>e</sup> édition) :

> *en* et *y* ont une **valeur très imprécise**<sup>2</sup>, tantôt vaguement pronominale, tantôt vaguement adverbiale, dans un grand nombre d'expressions telles que : *s'en aller, s'en venir, s'en faire, s'en tirer, en vouloir à quelqu'un, s'en tenir à quelque chose, il en est ainsi, en avoir assez*, etc...

***La grande grammaire du français*** (p.1012) :

> Les [proformes](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/proforme) faibles figées :
> Les proformes faibles figées sont obligatoires et ne remplacent pas un sujet ou un complément. Elles ne sont pas référentielles et ne s'interprétent que comme une partie d'une expression figée (*en avoir assez, en venir aux mains, en voire des vertes et des pas mûres*). Dans certains cas le verbe admet aussi un complément qui n'est pas figé : *en avoir assez (de)*,  *s'y connaitre (en)* etc. (Paul s'y connait en architecture. // Paul en a assez de cette histoire. // Ils en sont venus aux mains.)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Je ne citerai que : *en avoir marre, en avoir ras le bol, en avoir sa dose, en avoir sa claque, en avoir ras la casquette*, etc., je dois en oublier.

<sup>2</sup> C'est moi qui souligne.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First, let's clear up that in the sentence

> J'en ai marre de ce virus !

*en* is a pronoun while *de* is a preposition. That is, while they appear to have the same meaning ("of"), they don't have the same function.

The preposition *de* is required for the indirect object *de ce virus*. In French, the indirect object requires a preposition, so that is why it must be in the sentence even if it has the same semantic meaning as the indirect object pronoun *en*. Or in other words, the preposition *de* isn't placed in the sentence for its semantic meaning alone, but for it's grammatical function as well.

Similarly, the indirect object pronoun *en* isn't placed in the sentence for its semantic meaning alone, rather it is a required part of the phrasal verb *en avoir marre*. In contemporary French, *marre* cannot be used without *en* or *avoir*, they are a fixed, or as @None has explained, "calcified", construction (no different than *rendez-vous* is a "calcified" construction).

So what happens in your sentence is, in essence, that a phrasal verb and an indirect object are constructed according to the rules of grammar and then combined. That two words in a sentence carry the same semantic meaning in part isn't uncommon. Here is a similar construction:

> J'**en** ai marre **de** ...
> Il **y** a ... **dans** ...

(You may note that English has a similar construction as well with the same repetition of meaning: ***There** is ... **in** ...*)

Comment: *en* and *de* **don't** have the same meaning.